# Big Oh notation and quantitative integral test

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-number-theory, asymptotics, analytic-number-theory

Theorem: Let $y<x$ be real numbers, and let $f:[y,x]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a monotone function, then we know that
$$\sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}:y\leq n\leq x}f(n)=\int_y^xf(t)\,dt+O(|f(x)|+|f(y)|)$$.

Prove that $$\sum_{1\leq n\leq x}\log(n)=x\log x -x+O(\log (2+x)),$$
or more generally
$$\sum_{1\leq n\leq x}\log^k(n)=xP_k(\log x)+O_k(\log^k (2+x)),$$
where $P_k(t)$ is a polynomial with leading term $t^k$ for $k=0,1,2,\cdots$.

Hence, or otherwise, prove that for non-negative numbers $k,l\geq 0$,
$$\sum_{1\leq n\leq x}\log^k(n)\log^l\frac{x}{n}=xP_{k,l}(\log x)+O_{k,l}(\log^{k=l}(2+x))$$ where $P_{k,l}(t)$ is a polynomial with leading term $l!t^k$.

By the above theorem, we have
$$\sum_{1\leq n\leq x}\log(n)=\int_1^x\log t\,dt+O(|\log 1|+|\log x|)$$
$$=[t\log t]_1^x-\int_1^xt\cdot \frac{1}{t}\,dt + O(\log x).$$
$$=x\log x - x +1+O(\log x)$$.
But then I don't know how it leads to the big oh error $O(\log (2+x))$. Similarly for the $\sum \log^k n$, I can use integration by parts repeated to get the polynomial term, but i'm not sure how it leads to the big oh error.

For the last sum $\sum \log^k(n)\log^l\frac{x}{n}$, I am not sure how to proceed cuz integration by parts seems to get messy.

Thanks a lot for the help in advance.

Comment: Note that $\log x \leq \log(2+x)$.

Comment: @CrackedBauxite Thanks, but what's the point of writing it that way when we have a sharper bound? I actually read the above question from Terence Tao's notes on analytic number theory (exercise 4): https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2014/11/23/254a-notes-1-elementary-multiplicative-number-theory/

Comment: @Ishigami It's just a way to ensure the bound will also work for small $x$. For instance, when $x=0$ the bound becomes $\mathcal O(1)$

Comment: whatever should be in big oh notation should always be a positive quantity.  (in tao's exercise $x\geq 0$, so $log(2+x)$ is positive, whereas $\log x$ may not be.

Answer (score 1):

For your question about $\log (2+x)$ I answer it in a comment above.  For the question about $(\log n)^k(\log x/n)^l$ you are forgetting one of your logarithm properties:)

> $(\log x/n)^l=(\log x-\log n)^l=\sum _{r=0}^l(\log x)^r(-\log n)^{l-r}$ so $\sum _{n\leq x}(\log n)^k(\log x/n)^l=-\sum _{r=0}^l(-\log x)^r\sum _{n\leq x}(\log n)^{l-r+k}$